# Angular 2+ - Can I make a directive that makes use of router navigation?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-directive

I'm using Angular 5 and am trying to solve a problem where I have a string that looks like this:

`This is an herbal kind of [tea] found in the...`

and output something like this:

`This is an herbal kind of <a [routerLink]="['/help', 'tea']">Tea</a> found in the...`

Where the anchor tag is clickable and flows through Angular's routing mechanisms without requiring any sort of an absolute URL.

I was thinking I might be able to do this with a Directive, but I wasn't sure that the outputted results would be properly evaluated by the framework.

Formatting isn't as important to me as consistent routing, otherwise I'd consider something Markdown-oriented like Showdown.

Comment: Is the original string coming from the server like that? Then you want to convert any text found in `[brackets]` to a `routerLink`?

Comment: It won't be evaluated. You would have to compile the HTML to have that working. But, in production mode, there is no compiler because the idea is precisely to compile everything at build time. What yo can do though, is to replace [tea] by a link, and add a click listener on that link, that uses router.navigate().

Comment: @JBNizet that was my fear as well. That sounds workable, I'll have to give that a try and post the final code here. I don't want to have a dependency on the compiler anyway, so that's just fine.

Comment: @Narm the strings are coming from data files, right now, probably JSON because I'm trying to package this as an Electron app that doesn't need internet access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions in the comments, I made a directive that parses the input and adds DOM elements to the decorated element based on the input, with bracketed terms outputting spans with onclick handlers that trigger Angular navigation. Here's an early working solution:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MaterialColor } from '../libraries/material-color.enum';
import { Logger } from '../shared/utility/logger';

/**
 * An Angular directive that takes in a string of content and parses out terms inside of brackets, treating them as links to new topics.
 */
@Directive({
  selector: '[emHelpLink]'
})
export class HelpLinkDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('emHelpLink') public helpContent: string = '';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private router: Router) {
    Logger.debug(`Help link directive: ${this.helpContent}`, el);
  }

  /**
   * Responds to the Angular onInit event. It's important to look at helpContent here as it may not be set during construction.
   */
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.parseText(this.helpContent);
  }

  /**
   * Parses the input text and adds spans to the native element this directive decorates, replacing bracketed terms with router links.
   * @param {string} input the text to translate
   */
  private parseText(input: string): void {
    if (!input) {
      return;
    }

    // Declare loop variables
    let remaining: string = input;
    let startIndex: number = remaining.indexOf('[');
    let endIndex: number = remaining.indexOf(']');

    /* We're going to loop through and find the first bracketed set of terms, then transform those to links. Items before this will be treated
       as spans, and items afterwards will be re-evaluated for bracketed terms. If no remaining brackets are detected (or no brackets are present)
       the remaining text will be output as a span.
     */
    do {
      startIndex = remaining.indexOf('[');
      endIndex = remaining.indexOf(']');
      if (startIndex >= 0 && endIndex > startIndex) {
        this.addSpanText(remaining.slice(0, startIndex));

        const substring: string = remaining.slice(startIndex + 1, endIndex);
        this.addHelpLink(substring);

        remaining = remaining.slice(endIndex + 1);
      }
    } while (startIndex >= 0 && endIndex > startIndex);

    if (remaining) {
      this.addSpanText(remaining);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Adds a span tag to the document with the specified text
   * @param {string} text the text to include in the span.
   */
  private addSpanText(text: string): void {
    if (!text) {
      return;
    }

    const span: HTMLSpanElement = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerText = text;
    this.el.nativeElement.appendChild(span);
  }

  /**
   * Builds a span tag for the given help text that will navigate to the help topic when clicked. This will be a span tag
   * styled as an anchor tag.
   * @param {string} text the text to display in the link.
   */
  private addHelpLink(text: string): void {
    if (!text) {
      return;
    }

    const link: HTMLElement = document.createElement('span');
    link.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    link.style.color = MaterialColor.blue;
    link.title = `View help on '${text}'`;
    link.innerText = text;
    link.onclick = (): void => this.onLinkClick(text);

    this.el.nativeElement.appendChild(link);
  }

  /**
   * Responds to a help topic link click event by triggering an Angular routing event.
   * @param {string} text the help topic clicked.
   */
  private onLinkClick(text: string): void {
    Logger.debug(`Help topic clicked ${text}`);

    if (!text) {
      return;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/help', 'topic', text]);
  }
}
```